# I want to hide/show button component in react native depending on state

Tags: react-native

I want to show at the beginning the reserve button and after the on press reserve is finished I need reserve button to hide and cancel button to appear and from then on vice versa. when one of the two buttons is visible the other disappear and vice versa.

my code:

```
const Unit = (props) => {
  const [isReserveButtonVisible, setVisibilty] = React.useState(true);
  const [isCancelButtonVisible, setVisibilty2] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Click here to reserve"
        visible={isReserveButtonVisible}
        onPress={() => {
          Alert.alert(
            "Please be noted that the unit is reserved for the next hour only ",
            ".",
            [
              {
                text: "Reserve",
                onPress: () => {
                  setModal(true);
                },
              },
              { text: "Cancel" },
            ]
          );
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Click here to cancel"
        visible={isCancelButtonVisible}
        onPress={() => {
          Alert.alert(
            "Please be noted that now you are canceling your reservation",
            ".",
            [
              {
                text: "Yes",
                onPress: () => {
                  setSwitch(true);
                },
              },
              { text: "No" },
            ]
          );
        }}
      />
      <Switch value={isSwitchEnabled} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [Button](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button#docsNav) doesn't have `visible` props

Second, your code have some problem seems not clear with `</View> and </Modal>`

Third, you could use statement to control if you want to show in render like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
...
export default function App() {
  const [isReserveButtonVisible, setVisibilty] = useState(true);
  const [isCancelButtonVisible, setVisibilty2] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>      
      {isReserveButtonVisible ? (
        <Button
          title="Click here to reserve"
          visible={isReserveButtonVisible}
          onPress={() => {
            setVisibilty(false);
            setVisibilty2(true);
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
      {isCancelButtonVisible ? (
        <Button
          title="Click here to cancel"
          visible={isCancelButtonVisible}
          onPress={() => {
            setVisibilty(true);
            setVisibilty2(false);
          }}
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

Take it a try :D

[Code example build on sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dust-hzg7m?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but i just had to put the {setVisibilty(false);
            setVisibilty2(true);} in another place as code is bigger and has more functions that that but it worked successfully thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers, and by [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer to any
question you ask. :)